# Comparing two different types with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Assume I have a `Posts` table with field `Owner` of type `Person` (which has field `Name`).

I'm trying to make this shorthand expression work:

```
from p in Posts where p.Author == "SomeNameAsString" select p;
```

Which means I would have to compare object of type `Person` with a `string`.

I tried to override `Equals` and to override operators == and !=, but I'm still getting exception "DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types.".

**Is there a way to make two different types comparable in Entity Framework?**

Comment: @Tomas Sorry, its the Person, I fixed it in the post.

Comment: I gave you a short answer below as well with a suggested solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF tries to translate your query into SQL, and while doing that it doesn't seem to take into account your type conversion operators. Simply use this query instead:

```
from p in Posts where p.Author.Name == "SomeNameAsString" select p;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is possible, I just wanted to see whether I can create a shorthand for this.

Comment: The short for this is `Posts.First(p => p.Author.Name=="blbbl");`

Comment: @WagoL: that's  not correct. Your code uses First instead of Where

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
 from p in Posts where p.Author.Name == "SomeNameAsString" select p;
```

(if `Name` is a property on `Author`)

Comment: Yeah this is definitally another option, if you compose the string within SQL you can do a compare, p.Author.FirstName + p.Author.LastName == "SomeNameAsString" will also work